# Scala extends Java Interface with type

Tags: java, scala, interface, type-parameter

I am curious how one would implement a Java Interface in Scala with the following signature;

```
public interface MyService<T> { ... }
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
object ServiceImplementation extends MyService[String] { ... }
```

would be an example.